# XMLHttpRequest in Edge (responseURL property)

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, microsoft-edge

Basically I use the responseURL variable that XMLHttpRequest's give back. The problem is for some reason my code wasn't working on Microsoft Edge, but it was on Chrome/Firefox.

You will also notice that the responseURL property isn't in the Edge docs,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(v=vs.85).aspx

but is in the Mozilla docs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest

**Is the responseURL property not available on Microsoft Edge? If so, are there any alternatives I can use?**

Comment: What code's not working? You haven't shown us any code or provided  proper problem description of exactly what it is you re trying to do

Comment: The `responseURL` property was added in newer builds of Microsoft Edge, and will be in general release builds in the near future. If you'd like early access to features, you can join the [Windows Insider Program](http://insider.windows.com/).

Comment: @Sampson Thanks so much! Good to know.

Comment: @charlietfl The code that isn't working is the responseURL property of an XMLHttpRequest

Comment: why do you need it in the first place? You already know where you make the request to

Comment: @charlietfl Because things can happen such as redirections

Comment: fine but curious what importance that is and what you would do with result?

Comment: @charlietfl Since you're curious, I've been using it for HTML5's new History feature. It allows you to set the path in the browser url bar. This means that you never have to actually leave a page, every link your press, it will retreive it with AJAX or something of the liking, then use document.write or an iframe to display it.

Comment: @charlietfl Example sites would be like SoundCloud or Youtube. Both of them never leave the first page you go on, and load new pages through code. That's also why they have those custom progress bars on top of the page.

Comment: responseURL is set with the value of the original URL, usually.

However, if there is an HTTP 307 redirect, responseURL should contain the value for new URL, thus it's different from the original URL.

XMLHttpRequest takes care of the redirection for us, so we don't have to worry about it, and the redirection is transparent.

On the other hand, if you want to handle that value (in my case, for handling DASH streams from redirected URL manifests), comparing the original URL with responseURL is the best (if not only) option to detect a redirect. And no, Edge hasn't implemented it yet :(

Comment: @chambs, how did you manage to get responseurl for redirected request? Thanks.

Comment: I am a little late to reply you, @BarbarosAlp, but there it goes hehe.
you can use xhr.responseURL once you get your answer from the xhr request. Here is a sample from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL

I hope I have answered the question. Let me know otherwise. Cheers!